# My Application throws an error when it starts at the same time as windows (Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium

I hope you are well, I need help, I am creating a software that starts at the same time as Windows with Selenium, this software opens a web browser in the background, but when the computer starts, I get this error:

[image]

But if I open my app again it works. How can I make it runs at the same time as Windows?

```
//register the application key
private void Start()
    {
        RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        if (rkApp.GetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()) != null)
        {
            rkApp.SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
        }
    }

private Dictionary<string, WebExplorer > _WebExplorer = new Dictionary<string, WebExplorer >()
    {
        ["chrome"] = new ChromeWebExplorer(),
        ["firefox"] = new FireFoxWebExplorer(),
        ["edge"] = new MicrosoftEdgeWebExplorer()
    };

    private DriverManager _Mananger = new DriverManager();

    private IWebDriver _Driver;

    public WebDriver(string WebExplorer , string Version)
    {
        Init(WebExplorer , Version);
    }

    private void Init(string WebExplorer , string Version)
    {
        _Mananger.SetUpDriver(_WebExplorer [WebExplorer].GetConfig(), Version);
        _WebExplorer[WebExplorer].Start().HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        _Driver = Navegadores[WebExplorer].GetDriver();
    }

 //A web explorer class
internal class MicrosoftEdgeWebExplorer: WebExplorer
{

    public MicrosoftEdgeWebExplorer()
    {
        _Options= new EdgeOptions();
    }

    public override IDriverConfig GetConfig()
    {
        return new EdgeConfig();
    }

    public override IWebDriver GetDriver()
    {
        var Options = _Options as EdgeOptions;
        Opciones.AddArguments(_Arguments);
        return new EdgeDriver(_Service as EdgeDriverService,Options);
    }

    public override DriverService StartService()
    {
        _Service= EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        return _Service;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include information about how this "runs when the computer starts?" Very likely this is a permissions issue with the user running the application as the computer starts up.

Comment: @GregBurghardt How Can I know Which User is running?, the application start with registry key on windows "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run" and the value is the application execute path

Comment: You should be able to search online for which user runs an application when it gets started automatically when Windows starts. That user should have permissions to run the browser. If they don't, try configuring the program to run as a user that does have permissions. Unfortunately we need a lot more information to answer this question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt What information do you need?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I just realized that C:\WINDOWS\System32\Edge\101.0.1210.32\x64 doesn't exist, but why if I run the app by clicking on it, it works?

Comment: It doesn't exist because of a permissions issue. The user running the application when the computer starts **does not have read permissions** to that directory. The directory exists. This is a permissions issue. Can you [edit] your question to include information on how you are running this application at startup?

Comment: There are two normal methods to start a programm automatically during start-up a computer/server. 1. You are using "autostart" 2. You are using a "Service" for this job. Please tell us more about your start-up session.
In case 1: Did the user has rights?
In case 2: Did the Service get startet as Admin? What start-up did you use?